# 'React/RCTViewManager.h' file not found from FBSDK in react native 0.60

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-fbsdk

I recently upgraded react-native to version 0.60. As a consequence, my Podfile looks like this:

```
target 'myProject' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for myProject
   # this is very important to have!
    rn_path = '../node_modules/react-native'

    pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'
    pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
    pod 'React-DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
    ...
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
```

One of the project dependencies is FBSDK, as it is shown above. 
The problem is that this dependency relies on React pod instead of React-Core, so the build fails because some modules are not found using the path React/Module:

Xcode, File RCTFBSDKMessageDialog.h (from the pod react-native-fbsdk):

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>

@interface RCTFBSDKMessageDialog : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
@end
```

I get the error: **error 'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found**

If I change it for React-Core/React/RCTBridgeModule.h it works.

Any idea to make it work without renaming all the references?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it finally.

The problem was on the Podfile, the last part was removing React from the ios project target(I had this for the previous React version):

```
  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == "React"
        target.remove_from_project
      end
    end
  end
```

And I had to add this lines as well (from [React Native Upgrade helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.59.10&to=0.60.0)):

```
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

...

use_native_modules!
```

So, in conclusion, the problem was that after upgrading to 0.60, the Podfile was not correctly upgraded so React module was not added to the iOS target.